# JBoss Server Stopping

Tags: linux, jboss

I'm having a problem with keeping a JBoss server running.  Here's the command I'm using to start it:

```
sudo /JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh conf -b servername.domainname.tld
```

JBoss starts okay after about 4 minutes or so, and when I `ps` it, it shows up as a process.  However, if I happen to log out of `SSH` and `ps` again, it's been stopped.  Is there a way to start the server so it doesn't automatically stop when a user logs out of SSH?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem here is the standard output stream.

Redirect the output to a file and start the process in background like following.

```
sudo /JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh conf -b servername.domainname.tld > log_file &
```

This may help.